# vs2012 web essentials won't auto compile less files on save

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

I'm using Web Essentials 2012 version 1.8.5 , 
for some reason it won't auto compile less files to CSS.
when I hit the save after I've made some changes to the less files I can see "web essentials compiling file.less" on the status line for a split of a second but nothing really happen. eg. the fils.css is not really changing.

Did someone have the same problem? or is someone knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

p.s
I did try the uninstall/install

Comment: I don't know if it will solve your problem, but there is a more recent release of WE 2012: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6 (Version 1.9.2 at time of writing)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed and you can download the latest version (1.9.2) right here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

Comment: on the subject, I found the compiler to be quite slow compare to the VS Less plugins, is there a reason for this?